# Manually updating jquery pagination plugin after partial page refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins

I have an asp.net-MVC project and I have implemented a paging mechanism using [this](http://beneverard.github.com/jqPagination/) plugin.

On the first page I have products and a pager that calls a controller method returning the next page of products. This all works fine. The problem is, that I also have an option to update the products via buttons on that same page. In case I update the products with a button and NOT with the pager links the products are updated, but the pager plugin is not.

I need to manually update the pager and change the max_page number and the "null" in the updateRecentBooks to another value when the page is updated when not using the pagination plugin.

```
$().ready(function () { 
 $('.pagination').jqPagination({
        max_page: @Model.NumberOfPages,
        paged: function(page) {
            updateRecentBooks(page, null);
        }
    });
});

 $("#button").live("click", function () {
        ...
        // Calls the updateRecentBooks with the proper value

        updateRecentBooks(1, properValue);

    });
```

After the click event happens, the NumberOfPages attribute is updated and I need the pager to be updated to reflect the changes and look like this:

```
 $('.pagination').jqPagination({
        max_page: @Model.NumberOfPages, // Now contains new values.
        paged: function(page) {
            updateRecentBooks(page, propervalue); // Now contains proper value.
        }
    });
```

How should I go about solving this problem? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Try to destroy and recreate your jqPagination control when the user clicks #button.

Comment: Okay, so I have narrowed it down to this: `alert(@Model.NumberOfPages);  updateRecentBooks(1, facId);  
alert(@Model.NumberOfPages);`
although the updateRecentBooks updates the @Model.NumberOfPages it is still the same in both alerts. I debugged and the controller passes the right value to the viewmodel. Why is it not available right after that ajax request?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved the problem by moving the pagination controls inside the panel I was updating with ajax. This way the pagination control gets rebinded with new values every time I update the partial view.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i'm understand you right... but why not make another server side variable loaded there then?

```
updateRecentBooks(page, @Model.CurrentPage || null);
```

Comment: The  $("#button").live("click", function () does do that, but I need the pager to update. The updateRecentBooks only updates the contents of the page. The page numbers are still the same as before I called that method, because the $('.pagination').jqPagination values are not updated.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can get it to happen as there doesn't seem to be a public function in the plugin to do it properly is to re-initialise the jqPagination() with the new default options I want after the ajax request returns..